# What is the median of Bernoulli distribution?

Tags: probability, self-study, median

By [definition of median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median#Formal_definition), i.e.

> $P(X\leq m)\geq 1/2 \text{ and } P(X\geq m)\geq 1/2.$

What is the median of Bernoulli distribution with a probability parameter of $p=0.2$ ($P(X=1)=0.2$)?

Suppose $m$ is the median. Then $P(X\leq m)\geq 1/2$ implies $m\geq0$. $P(X\geq m)\geq 1/2$ implies $m<0$. One says m is greater or equal to 0 and the other says it is strictly less than 0. I don't understand where I did wrong.

Here are the CDF plot[image].

Comment: Your second deduction is incorrect: $P(X\ge m)\ge 1/2$ implies $m\le 1.$

Comment: Is it $m\leq 1$ or $m < 1$? The CDF is right continuous and so is 1-CDF?

Comment: There are only three intervals to consider.  For $m\le0,$ $\Pr(X\ge m)=1;$ for $0\lt m\le1,$ $\Pr(X\ge m)=0.8;$ and otherwise for $m\gt 1,$ $\Pr(X\ge m)=0.$ (I took the parameter to be $p=\Pr(X=0).$)

Comment: I updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Your plot of $S$ is incorrect: check its values at $0$ and $1.$

Comment: @whuber WOW. Thank you!

Comment: The second is wrong simply because $P(X\ge 0)=1$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $X \sim \mathsf{Bern}(p=.2)\equiv\mathsf{Binom}(n=1, p=.2).$ In R, where `qbinom` is the inverse CDF (quantile function) of a binomial distribution a median $\eta = 0.$

```
qbinom(.5, 1, .2)
[1] 0
```

$P(X \le 0) = P(X = 0) = 0.8 \ge 1/2.$

```
dbinom(0, 1, .2)
[1] 0.8
```

And obviously, $P(X \ge 0) = 1 \ge 1/2.$

The CDF of $X$ is plotted below. The **median** of $X$ is taken to be the value
at which the CDF 'curve' is (or 'crosses') $1/2.$

```
curve(pbinom(x, 1, .2), -.5, 1.5, n=10001, xaxs="i", ylab="CDF")
 k = 0:1; cdf = pbinom(k, 1, .2)
 points(k,cdf,pch=19)
 abline(h = .5, col="blue", lwd=2, lty="dotted")
```

[image]

Also, for context, if we simulate $1000$ observations from this distribution, we get $805$ Failures (0) and $195$ Successes. According to R, the **sample median** is also $0.$

```
set.seed(2020)
x = rbinom(1000, 1, .2)
table(x)
x
  0   1 
805 195 
summary(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  0.000   0.000   0.000   0.195   0.000   1.000
```

Comment: Re "various versions:" what version would give any different value in this case??

Comment: While making CDF curve, I realized the median is unique in this case. Deleted first line. In this example, there might be various versions of the 80th percentile.

Comment: +1 The plot of the CDF is helpful.

Comment: thank you. But I was asking the theoretical median of the Bernoulli but not based on simulation. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: The simulation is just to show how sample medians may emulate population medians. You need not take it as part of the formal answer to your question.

Answer (score 5):

$X \sim Bern(0.2)$

By the definition of median

$P(X \leq m) \geq 1/2$ and $P(X \geq m) \geq 1/2$

It has

$m = \begin{cases}
0, \quad p < 1/2\\
[0,1], \quad p = 1/2\\
1, \quad p > 1/2 
\end{cases}$

It then follows that $m = 0$.

Comment: Good. (+1). If $p=1/2,$ the median is ambiguous in $[0,1].$ R chooses $0:$ `qbinom(.5,1,.5)` returns $0.$. That's because the CDF has $F(0) = 1/2.$ That is:  `pbinom(0, 1, .5)` returns $0.5.$